# Slick Slider вертикальное пролистование на моб. устройствах

Tags: slider, slick.js

МБ кто в курсе, такая ситуация:
На десктоп версии все шикарно(вертикальное прокручиние) и т.д.
Но когда открываем с моб. устройств если пальцем листать слайдеры сверху вниз или наоборот, слайды не переключаются, а если справа на лево, то переключаются, хотя слайды идут по 1 на все разрешение экрана.
Собственно вопрос, как можно заставить переключаться слайды проводя пальцем не горизонтально, а вертикально...

Answer (score 1):

В настройках slick поставьте

```
verticalSwiping:true
```